# When does a multiplication table form a category?

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, algorithms, cayley-table

Fix a (finite) set $A$. Say you are given a Cayley (multiplication) table for $A$: an $|A| \times |A|$ matrix, where each row and column corresponds to exactly one element of $A$, and the entries of the matrix are elements of $A \cup \{ - \}$. For example, if $A = \{ a, b, c, d \}$:

$\begin{array}{c|cccc}
\circ & a & b & c & d \\
\hline
a & - & b & - & c \\
b & d & b & - & a \\
c & - & - & a & b \\
d & d & - & a & - \\
\end{array}$

Intuitively, we interpret the above table as follows. The entry in row $x$, column $y$ gives us the product $x \circ y$: either this is another element $a \in A$, in which case we say $x \circ y = a$, or it is "$-$", in which case we say $x \circ y$ is undefined. So, any such table defines a partial magma on $A$.

Now, interpret the elements of $A$ as morphisms, with composition defined as above. **Is there an algorithm to determine whether this set of morphisms forms a category?** That is, if we let $\operatorname{Hom}(\mathbf{C}) = A$, is there a set of objects $\operatorname{Ob}(\mathbf{C})$, and functions $\operatorname{source}, \operatorname{target}: \operatorname{Hom}(\mathbf{C}) \to \operatorname{Ob}(\mathbf{C})$ such that these obey the [axioms of a category](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_(mathematics)#Definition)?

---

Some ideas:

- There must be at least one object. If any product is undefined, there must be at least two objects. [A product $x \circ y$ is undefined iff $\operatorname{source}(x) \neq \operatorname{target}(y)$ - this could help].
- We need to assign source and target objects to each morphism, then check this assignment is consistent with the rules of a category.
- Identity would be easily checked for each object: associativity is a bit harder, but surely this has been done for a (partial) semigroup before?

**Bonus question:** how could this be done for other, single-operation algebraic structures? What about for multiple operations (rings, fields, vector spaces etc.) and providing multiple tables?

Comment: For your given example, it won't work because there are no identities.

Comment: If the table were for a groupoid, then the same procedure (ie sudoku-validity) applies *provided* there is a coherent assignment of src,tgt objects to each morphism. Without identities, you have a semigroupoid ;-) More generally than a category ;-)